# .htaccess on wordpress site keeps going blank

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, plugins, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress WooCommerce site with a few different plugins. Lately, about once a month any attempt to load any page besides the home page results in a 404 error. I've figured out this is because something is resetting the .htaccess file to be completely blank. Once i re-upload my backup it gets fixed. Looking for answers online, it seems it could be a plugin causing this but I don't know which one, nor why now? I also see advice about # BEGIN Wordpress ... # END Wordpress but that's already there on the .htaccess file, along with some other code that I'm not exactly sure where it came from. Any advice on how to prevent this from happening? My .htaccess permissions are currently 644 and here is my code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
 AddType application/x-javascript .js
 AddType text/css .css
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/javascript
 <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be a plugin that is clearing the file; you will need to deactivate them all and reactivate, and that will take some time waiting to see which plugin is the issue.

Try setting the file permission to 444 and see if that stops the file from being written to and saved as blank. 444 permissions will only allow root to write the file, not normally the permissions a plugin has. If the file still gets blanked out at 444, it's probably a server issue or a badly engineered plugin, since root is still able to write to the file.

You can even go to 440 or 400 permissions, as long as WordPress continues to be able to read the file and work OK.

This could also be malware; when you restore a backup, do you mean you restore only the .htaccess file or the whole site? Have you replaced all word WP files and folders with good copies? Have you scanned the site for malware?

The other code in .htaccess is adding browser gzip compression; it's not hacking code and won't be causing the file to be saved as blank. It's either been aded manually, or was added by a plugin.